# Get old value in before_save or before_update using "_was'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I am using Rails 2.3 and trying to have the submission date of a form changed *only* the first time that all required fields are filled.

Here's what I tried, both in `before_save` and `before_update`:

```
if ((self.required_fields_filled == true) and (self.required_fields_filled_was == false)) 
      self.submitted_at = Time.now
end
```

As long as `required_fields_filled` is currently true, it always updates `submitted_at` to `Time.now`

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: i think you should not use `required_fields_filled` for your requirement `only the first time` since there's a case that `required_fields_filled == true` and `required_fields_filled_was == false` at the {n} times (e.g user fill all at the first time, next time he remove a field, then he update again with full fields <-- this case). Actually it's easy to implement your requirement  by checking the field `submitted_at` is `nil`(1st time) and all fields filled (on logic, no need a db field).

Comment: problem is - I want users to be able to fill out a form and save their progress *without* filling out all the required fields, then have the form submitted once all required fields are filled out. Hence I need both qualifications.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
if (self.required_fields_filled == true)
      self.submitted_at ||= Time.now
end
```